# How can I share a specific srcSet/configuration with a downstream module?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have `:A` (upstream module).

Inside `:A`, there's a `src/fakes/java` that I want to share with downstream modules. This contains fake implementations of interfaces within `:A` that are useful for testing purposes. I want to include it within `:A` for tests, and optionally expose it for downstream consumers.

**`:A`'s build.gradle**

```
android {
  sourceSets {
    fakes {
      java {
        srcDir android.sourceSets.main.java
        srcDir 'src/fakes/java'
      }
    }
    test.java.srcDir 'src/fakes/java'
  }

  configurations {
    fakes
    fakes.extendsFrom(main)
    fakes.transitive false
  }
}
```

}

**`:B`'s build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
  compile project(path: ':A')
  testCompile project(path: ':A', configuration: 'fakes')
}
```

However, when compiling test classes within `:B` that reference classes within `:A`'s `src/fake/java`, I get an unresolved reference error. This is because `:A` does not build an `.apk` for the `fakes` configuration.

How can I achieve this? I'd prefer not to utilize Android's product flavors if possible.